# Using the SSIM method for large images

Tags: python, numpy

I'm try to implement the [SSIM](https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~z70wang/research/ssim/) method. This method has already been implemented in Python ([source code](http://isit.u-clermont1.fr/~anvacava/code.html)), but my goal is implement it with using only Python and NumPy.

My goal is also to use this method on big images (1024x1024 and above). But `filter2` works very slow (approx. 62 sec. for 1024x1024). cProfile gives me information that **_methods.py:16(_sum)**, **fromnumeric.py:1422(sum)**, and **method 'reduce' of 'numpy.ufunc' objects** eat main part time of run.

```
import numpy

def filter2(window, x):
range1 = x.shape[0] - window.shape[0] + 1
range2 = x.shape[1] - window.shape[1] + 1
res = numpy.zeros((range1, range2), dtype=numpy.double)
x1 = as_strided(x,((x.shape[0] - 10)/1 ,(x.shape[1] - 10)/1 ,11,11), (x.strides[0]*1,x.strides[1]*1,x.strides[0],x.strides[1])) * window
for i in xrange(range1):
    for j in xrange(range2):
         res[i,j] = x1[i,j].sum()
return res

def ssim(img1, img2):
    window = numpy.array([\
        [0.0000,    0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0001, 0.0002, 0.0003, 0.0002, 0.0001, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],\
        [0.0000,    0.0001, 0.0003, 0.0008, 0.0016, 0.0020, 0.0016, 0.0008, 0.0003, 0.0001, 0.0000],\
        [0.0000,    0.0003, 0.0013, 0.0039, 0.0077, 0.0096, 0.0077, 0.0039, 0.0013, 0.0003, 0.0000],\
        [0.0001,    0.0008, 0.0039, 0.0120, 0.0233, 0.0291, 0.0233, 0.0120, 0.0039, 0.0008, 0.0001],\
        [0.0002,    0.0016, 0.0077, 0.0233, 0.0454, 0.0567, 0.0454, 0.0233, 0.0077, 0.0016, 0.0002],\
        [0.0003,    0.0020, 0.0096, 0.0291, 0.0567, 0.0708, 0.0567, 0.0291, 0.0096, 0.0020, 0.0003],\
        [0.0002,    0.0016, 0.0077, 0.0233, 0.0454, 0.0567, 0.0454, 0.0233, 0.0077, 0.0016, 0.0002],\
        [0.0001,    0.0008, 0.0039, 0.0120, 0.0233, 0.0291, 0.0233, 0.0120, 0.0039, 0.0008, 0.0001],\
        [0.0000,    0.0003, 0.0013, 0.0039, 0.0077, 0.0096, 0.0077, 0.0039, 0.0013, 0.0003, 0.0000],\
        [0.0000,    0.0001, 0.0003, 0.0008, 0.0016, 0.0020, 0.0016, 0.0008, 0.0003, 0.0001, 0.0000],\
        [0.0000,    0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0001, 0.0002, 0.0003, 0.0002, 0.0001, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000]\
    ], dtype=numpy.double)

    K = [0.01, 0.03]
    L = 65535

    C1 = (K[0] * L) ** 2
    C2 = (K[1] * L) ** 2

    mu1 = filter2(window, img1)
    mu2 = filter2(window, img2)

    mu1_sq = numpy.multiply(mu1, mu1)
    mu2_sq = numpy.multiply(mu2, mu2)
    mu1_mu2 = numpy.multiply(mu1, mu2)

    sigma1_sq = filter2(window, numpy.multiply(img1, img1)) - mu1_sq
    sigma2_sq = filter2(window, numpy.multiply(img2, img2)) - mu2_sq
    sigma12 = filter2(window, numpy.multiply(img1, img2)) - mu1_mu2

    ssim_map = numpy.divide(numpy.multiply((2*mu1_mu2 + C1), (2*sigma12 + C2)), numpy.multiply((mu1_sq + mu2_sq + C1),(sigma1_sq + sigma2_sq + C2)))
    return numpy.mean(ssim_map)

def calc_ssim():

    img1 = numpy.array(numpy.zeros((1024,1024)),dtype=numpy.double)
    img2 = numpy.array(numpy.zeros((1024,1024)),dtype=numpy.double)

    return ssim(img1, img2)
```

Comment: Can this be updated to Python 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your strided `filter2`, `x1` is `(1014, 1014, 11, 11)`.  You are iterating over the 1st 2 dimensions in order to sum on on the last 2.  Let `sum` do all the work for you, `res = x1.sum((2,3))`

```
def filter2(window, x):
    range1 = x.shape[0] - window.shape[0] + 1
    range2 = x.shape[1] - window.shape[1] + 1
    x1 = as_strided(x,((x.shape[0] - 10)/1 ,(x.shape[1] - 10)/1 ,11,11), (x.strides[0]*1,x.strides[1]*1,x.strides[0],x.strides[1])) * window
    res = x1.sum((2,3))
    return res
```

In my tests this gives a 6x speed improvement.

With `numpy` iteration, especially nested ones over large dimensions like `1014` is a speed killer.  You want to vectorize this kind of thing as much as possible.

Traditionally Matlab had the same speed problems, but newer versions recognize and compile loops like yours.  That's why your numpy is so much slower.

Comment: thank you, for explanation! On my machine execute time reduced to ~4.3 s.